# ScrollView react native not scrolling when using a map inside

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I'm using a scroll view in my project and it seems to work completly fine when I pass single components such as View or Image but when I try to map a list the ScrollView scroll is not working correctly.
My code is the following:

```js
export default function CompanyCards({ route, navigation }) {
  var companies = [
    {
      message: 'hello world0',
    },
    {
      message: 'hello world1',
    },
    {
      message: 'hello world2',
    },
    {
      message: 'hello world3',
    },
    {
      message: 'hello world4',
    },
    {
      message: 'hello world5',
    },
    {
      message: 'hello world6',
    },
    {
      message: 'hello world7',
    },
    {
      message: 'hello world8',
    },
    {
      message: 'hello world9',
    },
    {
      message: 'hello world10',
    },
    {
      message: 'hello world11',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {companies.map((company, index) => {
        return (
          <View id={index}>
            <Text>{company.message}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

I searched some solutions but all of them insist on putting flex:1 or minHeight:'100%' but still not working properly

Comment: Working Perfectly fine for me. Check out [this](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/scroll-view-demo) Snack.